# EF Core already tracked entity with same id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I can't figure out how to get rid of the error:

> The instance of entity type 'Relation' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 26}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I tried detaching the entities from the context, but even that did not prevent this error from happening. Can someone point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Service:

```
private async Task<int> EditAsync(RelationModel model)
{
    RelationEntity entity = _mapper.ToEntity(model);
    RelationEntity oldRelation = await _relationRepository.GetRelationAsync(entity.Id);
    _relationRepository.UpdateRelation(oldRelation, entity);
    await _relationRepository.SaveAsync();
    return entity.Id;
}
```

Repository:

```
    public void UpdateRelation(Relation oldRelation, Relation relation)
    {
        if (oldRelation != null)
        {
            // Detach
            Context.Entry(oldRelation).State = EntityState.Detached;

            // Delete childs
            if (oldRelation.Person != null && relation.Person == null)
            {
                Context.Persons.Remove(oldRelation.Person);
            }

            if (oldRelation.Customer != null && relation.Customer == null)
            {
                Context.Customers.Remove(oldRelation.Customer);
            }

            if (oldRelation.Supplier != null && relation.Supplier == null)
            {
                Context.Suppliers.Remove(oldRelation.Supplier);
            }

            if (oldRelation.Employee != null && relation.Employee == null)
            {
                Context.Employees.Remove(oldRelation.Employee);
            }

            // Update parent
            Context.Relations.Update(relation); // <-- error occurs
        }
    }
```

`Relation` entity:

```
public class Relation : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RelationRelations> ParentRelations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RelationRelations> ContactPersons { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RelationContactMethod> ContactMethods { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RelationAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried replacing

```
Context.Relations.Update(relation);
```

with

```
Context.Entry(oldRelation).CurrentValues.SetValues(relation);
```

but then none of my properties on the `Relation` entity get updated.

**UPDATE 2**

When running the following code

```
Context.Entry(oldRelation).CurrentValues.SetValues(relation);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

I can see that old relation is updated with the new values, but they aren't being applied to the DB... Why is that?

Comment: Instead of updating your `relation`, update your `oldRelation` one. Looks like both relations is technically the "same" relation but with updated values (because this is an edit right?).

Comment: correct, but how do I update the `relation`? Do I have to itterate over EVERY property? Cuz the  entity has a lot of properties that have other objects inside them

Comment: You would have to I'm afraid, but there are ways to make that easier by creating a class or method to do that. Alternatively, I see you're using a mapper, so mapping the `relation` parameter from your EditAsync method to the `oldRelation` might be an option, then save your old relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this  code instead of "Update" for many many years, everything always was updated properly  and I never had any errors.

It is never good idea trying to use generic code for EF. Try to select this way if you want to update several classes:

```
 var oldrelation = Context.Relations
.Include(i=> i.Person)
.Include(i=> i.Company)
...
.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id=entity.Id);
```

Replace

```
 Context.Relations.Update(relation);
```

with

```
Context.Entry(oldRelation).CurrentValues.SetValues(relation);
```

Comment: I already tried that, and you are right, that doesn't give an error. But the thing with Update is that it also updates properties that are changed inside (for instance) the Person object. And with Context.Entry those properties do not update. So how do I also update the properties of the Person object when I use the Context.Entry?

Comment: If you have some extra entities in your new relation,  you  will have to include them in your  old relation object. This way it will update all of them.

Comment: But there is an already existing property (Relation.Code) on both old and new entities. When I change the Relation.Code property with a new value, the value in de DB is not getting updated with that line of code you suggested.

Comment: Could you post your relation class pls.

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: I am sorry but but  none of my properties on the Relation entity get updated is not true. I am using this instead of update for many years, and never had any error.

Comment: okay, thanks anyway. Now I am at least a step further and maybe there goes something else wrong in my code on a deeper level

Comment: I added a update 2, could you please take a look at that question?

Comment: When I use `Context.Entry(oldRelation).CurrentValues.SetValues(relation);` I also need to add `Context.Entry(oldRelation).State = EntityState.Modified;` So for every object I update with the `Context.Entry()` I have to manually change the state. Is that the way to go?